# Lock sumif to specific cell range

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that contains data in columns A:D. Each block of data A1:D11, A12:D22, etc. represents a single days worth of data. It has configuration items that I do a sumif function on to pull for the grand total since the report began(=SUMIF(A:A,L2,B:B). I have now been asked to sum only the last weeks worth of data. My current formula is (=SUMIF(A1:A55,L13,B:B)-very simple. However, I need it to lock so that we only checks data between A1:A55. If I add in a new days block of data it changes the reference to (=SUMIF(A12:A66,L13,B:B). If I use the $ refernce it does the same thing...how do I lock the formula so that it will always look between A1:A55?

Regards

Comment: Maybe `INDIRECT("A1:A55")` is what you need.

Comment: `=SUMIF($A$11:$A$55,L13,$B$11:$B$55)`

Answer (score 1):

When you do some deletions or insertions, excel will shift the reference used in the formula automatically. e.g. If the original formula in B1 is `=SUM(A1:A20)`, after inserting cell A5 with shifting cells down , the formula will be `=SUM(A1:A21)`.

To avoid this situation, you can use the formula `INDIRECT`, it will return the reference decided by the argument with `string` type. Since it is a string, excel will not change its value, therefore the range will always be the same no matter you inserted or deleted something.

So give it a try =)

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT("A1:A55"),L13,B:B)`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative suggestion, I would create another column in your table that calculates the weeknumber from the date using `weeknum()` and then use `sumif` to lookup a specific week.

That way you don't need to worry about row inserts at all.

By using the `Indirect()` method (which is a good solution and may be be all you need to solve your problem), you still have the problem of data being inserted into the range that your `sumif()` covers that might not be part of the week that you're monitoring (for example, if a row containing data from a different week were to be entered into A55).